# How to have multiple backgrounds which have different shapes using only css?

Tags: css, background-color, linear-gradients, border-radius

I would like to create a two-layer background for the selected date in our time picker component, where the top layer is a circle and the bottom layer is a half-sized square.

This is what I have

[image]

here is the ideal result

[image]

I tried using `linear-gradient` to make it half and in order to make the top one as a circle, I used `border-radius: 50%` but that also applies to the bottom background I have

Any hint would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_shapes.asp

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your current code.

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with radial-gradient as well as linear-gradient for this.

Just to get you started, here is an approximation - you will want to alter the various dimensions to get exactly what you want for the calendar.

```css
.bg {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side at 25%, blue 0, blue 100%, transparent 100%, transparent), linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0, transparent 25%, cyan 25%, cyan 100%);
    background-size: 100% 100%, 75% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 25% 50%, 0 0;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use also `radial-gradient`

```css
.background {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 25%, #1565C0 5%, #1565C0 31%, transparent 31%), linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0, transparent 25%, #CCE1F5 25%, #CCE1F5 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
```